# Word VBA: how can I tell if a word has formatting, and then modify it if it does?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to create a script that will convert regular Word doc formatting into wikiformatting for my company's internal content system. For example:

**This is bolded** => "__This is bolded__"

I've been trying to do it through Word VBA but I'm struggling to make any progress at all. (For what it's worth, I have a lot of familiarity with Excel VBA.) This is what I have so far:

```
Sub convertFormatting()
    For Each sentence In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        For Each w In sentence.Words
            If w.Font.Bold = True Then
                newWord = "__" & w
                Debug.Print "Great, I figured out that it's bold. Now what?"
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

i started by recording a macro to search for "bold formatting" (no search text ... format ... font ... bold)

then used the "watch window" to examine "*Selection*" object when the program was paused right after the "*Selection.Find.Execute*" line

```
Sub convertBold2wiki()

    With Selection.Find             ' this sets up the "find" parameters
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
    End With

    Dim txt As String
    Dim found As Boolean

    Do While True
        found = Selection.Find.Execute    ' returns false on "not found"

        If Not found Then Exit Do

        txt = Selection.Range.Text        ' this is the found text
        Debug.Print txt
        Debug.Print Selection.Start
        Debug.Print Selection.End


        Selection.Font.Bold = False       ' un-bold the found text, otherwise ... well you know

        If Len(Selection.Text) > 0 Then   ' make sure that you are not inserting text at cursor
            Selection.Range.Text = "__" & txt & "__"
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```